# Padding between items in Xamarin.Forms ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined the following Cell type in a Xamarin.Forms project:

```
    public MyCell() // constructor
    {
        var messageLabel = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        };
        messageLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Message"));

        var dateLabel = new Label
        {
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label))
        };
        dateLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Date"));

        var view = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { messageLabel, dateLabel  },
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        };

        View = view;
    }
```

This is called within a ListView, like so:

```
    public MyPage()
    {
        var listView = new ListView()
        {
            ItemsSource = GetAllitems(),
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCell)),
        };

        Content = listView
     }
```

When this renders on the screen each item is really squashed up against its neighbours. I tried adding padding to the StackLayout in the MyCell class, but doing so results in text going off the screen. I'd like to have a gap between each item.

I'm think it may be worth converting the view to use Xaml to make this more clear, so if its easier to achieve as Xaml I'd accept that as an answer!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `RowHeight` of the `ListView`?

Comment: Will that fix the height for all? So if an item had wrapped line of text the item would not increase?

Comment: try ti add the following to your ListView HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, Then add a padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the HasUnevenRows property to true on the ListView. That way you have more control over the cell size.

Also, leave RowHeight to its default value (-1).

Comment: edited the answer for clarity, as this worked for me with Padding = new Thickness(15) in the StackPanel

Comment: This is the best answer setting HasUnevenRows to true for a listview in a Xamarin project has allowed to have much better customization of the view.